# how can I find the average of the sums of a field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents that looks like this

```
{ parentId: 2,  childId: 4, data: 7 },
{ parentId: 2,  childId: 3, data: 5 },
{ parentId: 2,  childId: 3, data: 1 }
```

I would like to pull the average of the sum of the data grouped by the childId where the parentId = a specific ID.

for example the data I would like to return by a given parent ID (2) is

```
((5 + 1) + (7)) / 2
```

Is there are way to nest the `$sum` inside a `$avg` or do I just need to return a list of the sums grouped by the childId and then average them myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `$sum` data group by `childId` then find `$avg` of the sums.

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "parentId": 2 }}, 
        { "$group": { "_id": "$childId", "sumdata": { "$sum": "$data" }}},
        { "$group": { "_id": "null", "avgdata": { "$avg": "$sumdata" }}}, 
    ]
)
```

```js
{ "avgdata" : 6.5 }
```